# Analysis differentiability question

Tags: real-analysis

This is a homework question I am having a hard time getting started on.  If you might lend advice as to a first step it would be appreciated.

Suppose $f: (a, b) \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $|f'(x)<L|$ for all $x\in (a,b)$.

Prove that:

1) If $x<y \in (a,b)$ then $|f(x) - f(y)| < L|x-y|$

2) $f$ is uniformly continuous

Comment: Are you using epsilon-delta proofs?

Comment: Hint: Mean Value Theorem

Comment: I could use $\epsilon,\delta$ or MVT.  Now that I'm thinking more about it, MVT is probably the better jumping off point.